# How to combine another condition with multiple inner join in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three master table and one main table that require data from all mastertables

```
    positionmaster(position_id, position_name) values(101, 'SeniorPosition'),(102, 'JrPosition')
    designationmaster(des_id, des_name) values(201, 'Manager'),(202, 'Lead')
    employeeMaster(emp_id, emp_name, emp_role) values(1001, 'Thomas', 'developer'),(1002, 'Lee', 'Sales'),(1003, 'Tony', 'BA')
    projectmaster(project_id, project_name, project_description) values(1,'Kana','Kana Project'),(2,'Billing', 'BillingProject')
```

all the employee are in employeemaster table but in mainadtatable I have seperate column based on role like sales_employee_id, developer_emp_id and all the master table ids will be stored in maindatatable

```
    maindatatables(id, position_id, des_id, sales_emp_id, developer_emp_id, project_id) values (1, 101, 201, 1002, 1001, 1), (2, 102, 202, 1001, 1002, 2)
```

I want to write a query that will return the list of records from maindatatable and instead of id, need to populate the name
(in below dataset all the id's values are replaced with respective table name values, like if maindatamaster table sales_emp_id has 1001 and developer_emp_id has 1002 then it should replace with thomas and Lee

```
    1, 'SeniorPosition', 'manager', 'Lee', 'thomas', 'kana'
    2,  'JrPosition', 'Lead', 'thomas', 'Lee' , 'Billing project'
```

Masteratatable

```
    id    position_id   des_id   sales_emp_id  developer_emp_id   project_id
     1      101          201      1002            1001               1
     2      101          201      1001            1003               2
```

the the query should return

```
    1, SeniorPosition, manager, Lee, thomas, kana
    2, SeniorPosition, manager, thomas, tony, billingproject
```

here with inner join I am replacing the ids with name in below query:

```
   select mdm.id, pm.project_name, dm.des_name, em.emp_name AS sales_emp_name, em.emp_name AS 
   developer_emp_name, prm.project_name
   from maindatatables mdt 
   join positionmaster pm on (mdt.position_id = pm.position_id)
   join designationmaster dm on (mdt.des_id = dm.des_id)
   join projectmaster prm on (mdt.project_id = prm.project_id)
   join employeeMaster em on (mdt.sales_emp_id = em.emp_id) //can I put a where condition here to check the role
```

this query is working is bothe the sales_emp_id and developer_emp id is same like (both has 1001) but if sales_emp_id = 1001 and developer_emp_id = 1002 then it's returning values of 1002 for both the id's

I am using hibernate. please suggest some better solution.
Can someone help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join `employeeMaster` a second time:

```
select 
    mdm.id, 
    pm.project_name, 
    dm.des_name, 
    em1.emp_name AS sales_emp_name, 
    em2.emp_name AS developer_emp_name, 
    prm.project_name
from maindatatables mdt 
join positionmaster pm    on mdt.position_id = pm.position_id
join designationmaster dm on mdt.des_id = dm.des_id
join projectmaster prm    on mdt.project_id = prm.project_id
join employeeMaster em1   on mdt.sales_emp_id = em.emp_id
join employeeMaster em2   on mdt.developer_emp_id = em.emp_id
```